# Primefaces update table after on-cell editing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a data table with on-cell editing feature, and I want to update the data table to show the modified record by apply them a different style class.

Here are my problems:

- If i do not update the data table when the onCellEdit event fires, records are correctly updated, but I cannot see the applyed style class for modified rows.
- If I update the data table when the onCellEdit event fires and use the return key to update a value, all works fine, and I can see the applied style class for modified rows.
- If I update the data table when the on-cell edit event fires and use the mouse clic to update a value (clicking on another row or on another cell within the same row), only the first value is updated correctly; when trying to update other values, the onCellEdit event triggers before I can insert the new value, so the event triggers with *newValue=oldValue*, for all the subsequent changes.

The xhtml page:

```
<h:form id="frm_tbl_riv">
  <p:dataTable id="tbl_rilevazioni" var="rilevazione"
    value="#{rilevazioni.rilevazioni}" widgetVar="tbl_rilevazioni_id"
    editable="true" editMode="cell" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="350"
    rowKey="#{rilevazione.idRilevazione}" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{rilevazioni.selezionata}">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
      update=":tView:frm_tbl_riv:popup_rilevazioni" />
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{rilevazioni.onCellEdit}"
      update=":tView:frm_btn_riv" />
      <!-- update=":frm_btn_riv :frm_tbl_riv" -->
    <p:ajax event="contextMenu"
      listener="#{rilevazioni.onRilevazioneSelezionata}"
      update="@this" />

    <p:column headerText="#{msg['rilevazione']}" width="130">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg['rilevazione']}" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{rilevazione.descRilevazione}" id="descRil" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{msg['valore']}"
      styleClass="#{rilevazioni.isModificata(rilevazione) ? 'modificata' : ''}"
      width="30">
      <h:outputText value="#{rilevazione.valore}"
        rendered="#{!rilevazioni.isModificabile(rilevazione)}" />
      <p:cellEditor
        rendered="#{rilevazioni.isModificabile(rilevazione)}">
        <f:facet name="output">
          <h:outputText value="#{rilevazione.valore}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
          <p:inputText value="#{rilevazione.valore}"
            label="#{msg['valore']}">
        </f:facet>
      </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And the managed bean (view scoped):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "rilevazioni")
@ViewScoped
public class GestioneRilevazioniBean implements Serializable
{
  // ...

  public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event)
  {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage msg = null;
    Object nuovoValore = event.getNewValue();
    Object vecchioValore = event.getOldValue();
    int i = event.getRowIndex();
    RilevazioneGiornaliera r = rilevazioni.get(i);

    r.setIdUtente(userBean.getUserId());

    if (!nuovoValore.equals(vecchioValore))
    {
      try
      {
        RilevazioniService.getInstance().updateRilevazioneGiornaliera(r);
        modificate.add(r);
      } catch (Throwable ex)
      {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }

  public boolean isModificata(RilevazioneGiornaliera riv)
  {
    return modificate.contains(riv);
  }

  public boolean isModificabile(RilevazioneGiornaliera rilevazione)
  {
    // some logic
    return true;
  }
}
```

If I use:

```
update=":frm_btn_riv :frm_tbl_riv"
```

for the on-cell edit event, I obtain the behaviour specified on point 2 and 3. The same with *@form* or *@parent*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have founded a solution to update the style class to the modified cell after the onCellEdit event fires.

Data table:

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{rilevazioni.onCellEdit}"
    oncomplete="handleRilevazioniCellEdit(xhr, status, args);" />
// ...
// within the cell editor
<p:inputText id="rilevazioniCellEditInputtext" value="#{rilevazione.valore}"
        label="#{msg['valore']}" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function handleRilevazioniCellEdit(xhr, status, args)
{
    var modelInput = $('#parentId:' + args.rowIndex + '\\:rilevazioniCellEditInputtext');
    var cell = modelInput.parent().parent().parent();
    cell.addClass('modificata');
}
</script>
```

Managed bean, at the end of the *onCellEdit()* event:

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.addCallbackParam("rowIndex", event.getRowIndex());
```